# Why my return page is not working properly in laravel

Tags: laravel

This is my edit function

```
    public function edit($id)
    {   
    $notice = Notice::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(5);
    $single_notice = Notice::find($id);
    $update_request = 'yes';
    return view('teacher.editnotice')->withSingle_notice($single_notice)-
    >withUpdate_request($update_request)->withNotices($notice);
    }
```

This is my update function

```
     public function update(Request $request, $id)
     {
    $update_notice = Notice::find($id);
    $previous_date = $update_notice->demoOrfinal;

    $teacher_id = 1;
    $update_notice->notice      = $request->notice;
    $update_notice->teacher_id  = $teacher_id;
       $update_notice->save();
       Session::flash('success','Notice Has Been Updated. Thanks 
       :-)');$notice 
       = Notice::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(5);
       $id = "";
       $auth_permission = 'teacher';
       return view('teacher.notice')->withNotices($notice)-
       >withAuth_permission($auth_permission)->withId($id);
       }
```

When user will click for edit, edit function will send update `request = 'yes'` so that the update form div will visible. It is working perfect. But my problem is when user click update then update method should return to `http://localhost:8000/notice/` but it is returning me to `http://localhost:8000/notice/1(lastupdateteddataid)`
I am using laravel 5.4. My problem is why update function sending lats updated id after url.
Can anyone please help me to solve this please.

Comment: Your update method takes an `$id` as a route argument which means that the update URL will contain an id in it so `/1` is expected to be in there. The question is why is there a `(lastupdatedataid)` appended in there. That's not generated by the code here though.

Comment: no no. I am getting id. not`(lastupdatedataid)`. I just gave this for make it understand what is one here. So I got url like this : `http://localhost:8000/notice/1`. Can you please suggest me how i can remove this 1 from url.

Comment: Do you have an alternative way of keeping track of which id you need to update, like e.g. a session variable? If so then change your route definition in e.g. `web.php` to not take a parameter and read `$id` from the session (or whatever other magical way you have)

Comment: I have done it by `return redirect()->to('/notice')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of view try with route..i think it's work.

```
return redirect()->to('/notice')
                                ->withNotices($notice)-
           >withAuth_permission($auth_permission)->withId($id);
```

Comment: wow. It is working. Thank you soooo much. I am trying to do this from last night and at last you saved me boss